# How to lazy load with Dependency Injection Container?

Tags: php, dependency-injection, lazy-loading, ioc-container

I am new to Dependency Injection Containers and the like.

What I have is a User object that I would like to build with a container. The user, in my case, might have tons of Comment objects associated with him/her, but I won't need them on every request.

Before, I would have had the User model create and load the Comment models itself, but I realize that is a bad practice.

If I don't want to load all the Comment upon building the User (eg - if I'd like to lazily load the comments), how do I achieve this with DI and DIC?

NOTE:
I know there are solutions built, but I don't want to use them until I understand how they work. This is a theoretical question to learn the basics, and then I will most likely switch to an established framework.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think that loading dependencies in your Models is the responsibility of the Dependency Injection container. This is the job of an ORM, Data Access Objects or your application services. The DI container then is responsible for configuring and instantiating the ORM, DAO or services classes.

Comment: Don't hate my ignorance, but I thought that the job of a dependency injection container was to, in fact, inject the dependencies into the objects that need them, no? I think this is where I'm getting confused...

Comment: That is true, but a DI container is usually somewhat more static (re configuration via XML or a PHP file). I don't know about any container that can naturally pull information dynamically from a database. Application logic should stay in your application not in the DI container.

Comment: thanks for the response - so is teh DI container more interested in building framework objects? For example, controllers, loggers, etc? And then the business logic stuff is build more by an orm?

Comment: Exactly to the point. And your own application is some kind of framework as well. Your classes have no idea how they are being instantiated, they just provide the proper business logic based on the objects injected during creation.

Comment: Thanks again for the response! one last clarification (and you are making sense to me so far, btw) - for stuff like my models, the ORM would be doing the injecting, correct? In this case the ORM would act similarly to the DIC or IoC?

Comment: Well there would be some kind of Inversion of Control, but the main purpose of an ORM is data mapping and retrieval not instantiating an overall application. Oh and if you haven't yet, http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html is a great read on the topic

Comment: Thanks again, Daff, ill check that out! I'm still trying to figure out how to put this altogether. I'm fairly certain that my homebrewed perception that I've entrenched myself in works, but isn't smart while my code grows.